# The most basic thing I can write in D3 to see something

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, d3.js

I just want to start learning D3 and have a project in Rails to play around with it.

I have a running rail server - localhost - and I have written this in the index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    body { font: 12px Arial;}
    path {
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }
    .axis path, .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1; shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
</style>
<body>
<p> Hi i am here</p>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


</body>
```

now what is the most basic thing I can type there to start with and see something in the browser?

Comment: I don't understand what RoR has to do with it, or why the normal tutorials like [this one](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html) don't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code to draw a circle:

```
<script>
    d3.selectAll("body") //select the body
        .append("svg") // add an svg element to the body
        .append("circle") // add a circle to the svg element
        .attr("r", 40) // add attributes to the circle
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("cy", 50)
</script>
```

Here is a jsFiddle with your code "completed": http://jsfiddle.net/Bd7HA/

---

If you don't mean graphic stuff you can also do that, which will basically write "Hello World" inside the "body" tag.

```
<script>
    d3.selectAll("body").text("Hello World")
</script>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/Bd7HA/5/